# Magento 1.9 sessions using files on PHP 5.4

Tags: php, magento, session, php-5.4, magento-1.9

I ran into a problem this morning using file based sessions in Magento CE 1.9 under PHP 5.4. I was able to browse the site but whenever I tried to add something to cart, or login to the system it had the same effect as refreshing the page. I read a few threads on SO pointing blame at the cookie path/domain and HTTP only settings in the `core_config_data` table. I changed these to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can ascertain (I'm new to Magento) there is no way of specifying the session directory (even though config.xml makes it appear that you can). Instead I found that creating a symbolic link fixes the issue.

For example, to fix my session issues I used the following command;

```
ln -s /var/tmp /var/www/var/session
```

Comment: This also could be a symptom of having file/folder and ownership not allowing the Magento install to write to var/ and subfolders. Make sure they're fully writable by the web server.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I had permissions set at 777 to test and I still had the same problem. It didn't want to play ball until I moved sessions outside of my public facing web directory.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of server configuration issue then, probably security related. hmm.